# How to resize focus area of a QToolButton?

Tags: qt, qtoolbar, qtoolbutton

I've got a `QToolbar` with `QToolButtons`. The buttons receive focus with a manual `->setFocus()`. However I need the focus marking area (blue) to be expanded to the size of the full area as while hovered.

Is there a way to do that?

[image: Button with the focus and hover]
Hover + focus

[image: Buttons with focus]
Focus (1st button), hover (2nd button)

Comment: What style is that? Fusion?

Comment: No custom style applied. It's default.

Comment: OK, then tell us what OS is it? Windows? Linux? macOS? Each OS has its own style in Qt and can behave differently...

Comment: My app is going to be working on Linux (Debian, Ubuntu), Windows, and MacOs. It is smaller on Ubuntu and Macos. As far as I understand it shouldn't depend on an OS.

Comment: If you use default widget styles then these styles will be different on each platform. So I would expect these to look different. But without having a minimum reproducible example, we cannot help you here, unfortunately. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example